# Switch between normal and 10-feet interface

Tags: fonts, gui

Sometimes when I watch a movie or TV episode on my computer, I'd like to sit on my couch. Now sometimes you want to check some random fact being mentioned on wikipedia, or someone writes to me via instant messaging. I don't want to get up, my mouse & keyboard are wireless, but the fonts are just to small to see. In Firefox, you can at least ctrl++, but that is no help in skype or pidgin. Is there a quick way to switch between normal & enlarged fonts, possibly even buttons & icons etc.? Btw. I'm using xmonad, but I'm open to other suggestions if need be.

Answer (score 0):

This is an advanced trick, without the full details as I am posting in haste:

Configure the system to launch two different X servers, one at full resolution, and one at lower resolution.  Use the Control-Alt-Fkey sequence to switch between them.

Answer (score -2):

Make a shortcut in the shortcut section of the keyboard-settings. You can make a chortcut for zoom in, zoom out, text size etcetera.